# Connecting ColdFusion to CDN

Tags: coldfusion, cdn

I'm just wondering whether anyone out there has managed to connect up a ColdFusion based CMS to a CDN for content hosted within it ?

We currently have our own CMS and we make use of CKEditor and CKFinder to display content. However, we are noticing that it might benefit from taking advantage of a CDN for static content.

What I'm wondering is how does one go about connecting a CMS to a CDN? All I've been able to find is articles on using existing wordpress modules for connecting content for websites.

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably better suited for ServerFault

Comment: Which CMS? Which CDN? It is unclear what you are asking. For whatever it is worth, FarCry (a CF CMS) has built in support for managing files and images hosted on a CDN.

Comment: Not sure how using a CDN has anything to do with ColdFusion. To me using a CDN has to do with routing. You define your images, pdfs, etc to be served from a CDN; not the ColdFusion server. So those requests never reach the ColdFusion server.

Comment: I "think" he means, how can he handle a situation where a content editor uploads an image or a file, but instead of saving it to the CF server, upload it to a CDN. Though, again, it isn't clear what is being asked and I have voted to close it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to connect a CMS to a CDN that is not how CDNs work.

Let's say your assets are served on assets.mydomain.com to utilise a CDN you create an account with one and register a CName pointing at the CDNs servers let's say that is static.mydomain.com. On the CDN you configure assets.mydomain.com to be the origin for static.mydomain.com.

Now you reference all your assets in the HTML of your website using static.mydomain.com. This is where the CDN does its clever bit. When an asset is requested the CDN checks to see if it has it, if not it requests it from the origin and simultaneously caches it so the next time you are asked for that asset it returns it from the CDN cache.

So really to connect your CMS to the CDN as you ask is achieved by making sure that the assets are requested off of a domain you have configured as above.